# express - route middle ware how to determine if a response view is already rendered

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have created a custom route middle ware for express js.

Example:

```
var customRouter = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(res);
    next();
};
```

and in app.js

```
app.use(app.router); //express default router
app.use(customRouter); //my custom router which comes after express default router
```

My custom router comes after the express default router.  What I'm trying to achieve is that to determine if the default express router have already rendered a response or a view.

How do I determine in my route middleware if a view or a response is already rendered in the express route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, when a middleware sends a response, then `next()` is not called anymore. So your customRouter is not fired in a case, when default router handles a request.

But anyway, you can always check a response if it was already flushed: `res.finished` => (`boolean`)

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering why my middleware is always called even though the route is valid.  Turned out it was the css routes that made my middleware being called because I have my middleware before the static stylesheets route.